# How do we implement great animations we see on dribbble to an ios app?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, gsap

I'm a brand identity and ui/ux designer, i've been wondering how to implement these animations we see on dribbble on to native ios/android and hybrids. I do interaction animations on after effects and figma.

Any libraries for react native and native ios /android?

Comment: https://airbnb.io/lottie/

Comment: Oh okay, but can we do interaction like smooth scrolling, card transitions, open and close animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly are done with GSAP that is one of the best js libraries for web animations, I suggest you to read this article ;)
https://medium.com/notonlycss/starting-with-gsap-1148ffd7e20b

Answer (score 3):

I have spent a lot of time to convert Dribble interactions to real world apps.
Both `React Js` and `React Native`.

There are two ways.

You can develop them for lottie animations. using adobe after effects or so. But the animations won't have that control.

Second, You can use `react-spring` for ReactJs, It is based on `react-motion`.

It has a very powerful interpolation, which support a lot of inputs. It also supports React-Native(Partial).

On `React-Native` you can use the animated api and Pan Responder. It's bit hard to get hands on both in starting, but when you do. You could implement a lot.
You can combine, scroll events with Animated Api. etc etc.
For references I would give you some links.

https://www.youtube.com/user/wcandill/videos

https://www.react-spring.io/